# Why have there been frequent ceasefire violations on the Indo-Pakistani border?

Tags: india, terrorism, military, pakistan

Many BSF and Pakistani Rangers personnel have been claimed to have been killed. This has been continuing for many years. Neither government has taken the responsibility for this violation which doesn't seems possible.

Several attempts of peace talks have been unsuccessful. Many civilians have also been killed and injured as a result of the almost daily ceasefire violations. Why is this happening, why has no-one intervened, and what steps could be taken to resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 2):

**Why this happens**

India and Pakistan fought 3 major wars, 1947-48 , 1965 ,1971 and some more wars like that of Kargil in 1999 and of Siachin.

After the defeat of 1971, Pakistan knew very well that it was not possible for it to win a war against India.

So it decided to use the terrorist/Mujahideens created by US in Afghanistan against India. Later it created it's own.

When border infiltration increased, India decided to build the fencing and increased patrolling. The result was decreased infiltration. So to help terrorist infiltrate in India, Pakistan violates ceasefire and attacks Indian posts.

India retaliates, which leads to and endless cycle of deaths on both side. If India won't retaliate, it will be one sided(deaths only on Indian side).

<sup>This is not all, but this is the main reason. Others like revenge attacks by BAT and Para SF are other minor reasons</sup>

---

**Why no one intervenes**

Why would someone want to get unwanted trouble by getting into a fight between two nations with nuclear weapons? US, China etc advise both to keep good situation on border but that's all.

---

**Steps to resolve this**

Currently, the only way out seems to be an complete annihilation of either India or Pakistan. But this is very unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

the main reason of ceasefire violation on India-Pakistan borders is the provide the safeguard to the militants who want to enter in India. It some time do it for more political reasons, like  when there are talks between the higher command from both side, to stop or to affect the peace talk. infiltration is no doubt the main reason but we should also consider the political scenario behind it. We all know that there is complete decentralization of power in Pakistan so they misuse the military to stop the talks between the governments from both side by doing the sporadic incidents near border areas.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for ceasefire violations is mistrust between the two countries, India's will have its reasons and justification for public to show how Pakistan violated the cease-fire ( for e.g. Mujaheddin crossings) and Pakistan will have its evidences like civilian deaths ( especially on border areas that are not Mujaheddin crossing routes). The fact is this is just symptoms not the cause of these violations, the root cause still remains the main issue of Jumma and Kashmir and I personally think that Jumma and Kashmir's root cause is the rivers flowing from it.

We must keep in view the fact that Pakistan is not ( and will not be for a forseeable future) an existential threat to India while vice versa is true. Hence the onus is on far bigger adversary i.e India to manage and downplay as much as possible.

Answer (score -1):

**Why this happens**

India and Pakistan fought 4 major wars,

- **1947** - Pakistan attacked India and robbed a huge chunk of Kashmir for which India is still being harrowed.
- **1965** - Pakistan attacked Indian Kashmir, and India attacked Lahore. After huge losses, both sides went back to their own cuckoo's nest.
- **1971** - India attacked Pakistan and separated a huge landmass of Pakistan for which Pakistan is eternally grateful to India as this landmass has now become Bangladesh and was ranked as the [most corrupt country consecutively from 2001-2005](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/south_asia/4353334.stm), [doesn't have any democracy](http://indianexpress.com/article/world/bangladesh-pm-sheikh-hasina-blasts-chief-justice-amid-growing-row-4807339/), [bafflingly overpopulated](http://www.ucanews.com/news/searching-for-solutions-to-bangladeshs-overpopulation/77484), and [suffering from Indian hegemony](https://www.telegraphindia.com/1140107/jsp/frontpage/story_17760386.jsp).
- **1999** - Pakistan attacked India and India narrowly escaped losing a landmass as the USA sided with India and [Clinton threatened Pakistan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TTNRU607ZxI) with serious consequences.

After the narrow escape of 1999, India understood very well that it was not possible for them to win a war against Pakistan as they are like historic Afghan ruler of [Ghazni, Mahmoud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahmud_of_Ghazni), who robbed India in 17 occasions. So they decided to shift their gear to their soft power (**economy** and **Indian diaspora**) which is overwhelmingly backed by the West (predominantly the USA), as [India gave them a huge market for arms](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24956/what-is-the-total-amount-of-defense-deal-between-usa-and-india-right-now). Later India

1. Created their own establishments in [Afghanistan](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/indiahome/indianews/article-3437668/Why-India-remains-power-Afghanistan.html), [Kyrgyzstan](http://thediplomat.com/2015/04/indias-central-asia-policy-makes-comeback-in-kyrgyzstan/), and [Iran](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/news/politics-and-nation/inside-chabahar-the-iranian-port-city-that-borders-pakistan-and-where-alleged-spy-kulbhushan-jadhav-was-based/articleshow/58663212.cms) to wage a proxy war against Pakistan.
2. Sent their spy [*Kulbhushan Yadav*](https://www.thenews.com.pk/latest/205166-ICJ-delivers-order-on-Kulbhushan-Yadav-spy-case) to finance separatist movements in Baluchistan.
3. [Financing TTP](http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/pakistani-taliban-militants-raw-india-terrorism/1/939429.html) to conduct suicide attacks throughout Pakistan.

When these efforts didn't produce any favorable outcome, India decided to resort to erratic shelling along the border. The result was heavy civilian casualties.

So to help terrorists to continue their chaos in Pakistan, India violates ceasefire and attacks Pakistani posts. When Pakistan retaliates it leads to an endless cycle of deaths on both sides. If Pakistan doesn't retaliate, it will be a one-sided [propaganda war](http://thediplomat.com/2016/09/is-india-capable-of-a-surgical-strike-in-pakistan-controlled-kashmir/).

---

**Why no one intervenes**

The West is heavily biased towards India. This bias comes from 3 basic sources,

[Source](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/24903/why-is-indian-controlled-kashmir-not-freed-from-indian-control-yet/24919#24919)

1. India's religion and culture
2. Indian's economy
3. India's influence or lobby in the West

---

**Steps to resolve this**

Currently, the only way out seems to be strengthening Pakistani [economy](https://www.forbes.com/sites/panosmourdoukoutas/2017/09/28/cpec-lifts-pakistan-up-in-world-competitiveness-rankings/#29fc6c2f26f1) and military power so that Pakistan doesn't have to give a damn to the West to come to the aid of Pakistan.

Comment: I wonder if maybe this answer might have just an ever-so-little flint of subjectivety...

Comment: @OlivierPucher, it's not clear to me, what you wanted to say.

Comment: Olivier is using the rhetorical tactic of understatement to point out how obvious it is that the writer of this answer is not being objective in their assessment and has an obvious bias toward one of the countries involved.

Comment: @BryanKrause, human beings are inherently biased, that is what I tried to say in the 2nd section of my answer.

Comment: We all have biases, but it is generally preferred here to be as objective where possible, and source what we can of the rest so that criticism of answers (which is helpful) is distinct from criticism of the answerer (which is perhaps less helpful).

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt, have you tried to come up with the same suggestion to other answerers in this thread who are demonstrating their biases towards their respective parties? If not, why me?

Comment: To be clear I did not criticize your bias in this answer, I criticized your defense of your bias. I would like the answer to have a more neutral tone, but you do seem to have enough support to make me tolerant. What I take exception to is the idea that it is normal or right to display a clear bias in answers here.