# What is the total amount of defense deal between USA and India right now?

Tags: united-states, russian-federation, india

What is the total amount of defense order that the USA has bagged from India in billions during Obama and Trump's presidency?

How does it compare to the Indo-Russian contract during the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to http://ajaishukla.blogspot.in/2017/09/us-senate-eyes-10-billion-in-arms-sales.html :

> Over the preceding decade, the US has become India’s biggest defence
>   supplier with $15 billion in sales of C-17 Globemaster III and C-130J
>   Super Hercules transporters, P-8I Poseidon maritime surveillance
>   aircraft, CH-47F Chinook heavy lift choppers and AH-64E Apache attack
>   helicopters.

Couldn't get figures for deals with Russia for the range duration but from http://m.timesofindia.com/india/India-Russia-ink-pacts-that-will-lead-to-defence-deals-worth-Rs-72000-crore/articleshow/54871603.cms (article of 15 Oct 2016):

> Correcting the pronounced tilt towards the US in defence deals over
>   the last decade, India on Saturday inked pacts with Russia to acquire
>   advanced air defence missile systems, stealth frigates as well as
>   jointly produce light-utility helicopters. The three projects are
>   collectively worth an estimated $10.5 billion (over Rs 72,000 crore).

There are most likely more deals with Russia earlier than these three, but as per the first source US is leading with $15 billion.

---

**Update May 2018**

According to http://ajaishukla.blogspot.in/2018/05/india-caught-in-crossfire-as-us.html

> The United States of America (US) has leapt ahead of Russia as India’s
>   biggest supplier of new weaponry. A recent report from Parliament’s
>   Standing Committee on Defence reveals that, during the last three
>   years, US firms concluded 13 contracts with India, worth Rs 288
>   billion. In the same period, Russia got 12 contracts, valued at just
>   Rs 83 billion – not even one-third of the US bag.

A look at the trend over the years, which indicates that USA started taking over Russia 2015 onwards:
[image: Capital Procurement Contracts Signed by India with Foreign Countries]
Source: http://ajaishukla.blogspot.in/2018/05/india-caught-in-crossfire-as-us.html

Comment: WTF is a `crore`?

Comment: @anonymous 10 million https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crore

Comment: blogspot doesn't give me a lot of confidence. Perhaps you have something more official for the quotes. Or an assurance that ajaishukla is a serious news outlet.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt the blog is run by a reputed defence reporter/expert who currently works as consulting editor with a daily newspaper Business Standard. He had also worked with the news channel DD News and NDTV.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajai_Shukla